# Zend Framework 2 use custom HTML add form

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form

I have this html form:

```
<form role="form" action="<?php $this->url('insediamento', array('action' => 'add')) ?>" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group col-lg-5">
            <label for="indirizzoSedeIns">Indirizzo</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="indirizzoSedeIns" placeholder="inserisci Indirizzo">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-1">
            <label for="civico">Civico</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="civico" placeholder="n°">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
            <label for="istatProvincia">Cod. Istat Provincia</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="istatProvincia" placeholder="Istat Provincia">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
            <label for="istatComune">Cod. Istat Comune</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="istatComune" placeholder="Istat Comune">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-5">
            <label for="recapitoSede">Recapito Sede</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recapitoSede" placeholder="Recapito Sede">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
            <label for="istatComune">C.A.P</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="istatComune" placeholder="Istat Comune">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
            <label for="classificazione">Classificazione Insediamento:</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="classificazione">
                <?php foreach ($insediamenti as $insediamento) : ?>
                    <option><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($insediamento->description); ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
            <label for="longitude">Longitudine</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="longitude" placeholder="Longitudine">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-6">
            <label for="latitude">Latitudine</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="latitude" placeholder="Latitudine">
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox col-lg-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

how can I use it with Zend Framework 2?
I need to save this information, but I can't build this form with Zend Classes like $this->add, I have to create them with the HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a partial with the form:

Create a partial folder under your view directory and inside of it create a phtml file with your form html content.

Then in the 'view_manager' section of your module.config.php create an entry similar to 'layout/layout' but in this case the name could be 'myForm':

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_map' => array(
        'myForm'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/partial/myForm.phtml',
    ),
),
```

An to use it in any view you call it as follows using partial() View Helper:

```
<div><?php echo $this->partial('myForm', array('action' => $this->url('doAdd'))); ?></div>
```

Where in the second argument of the partial View Helper you can pass arguments to the partial. And in the partial you can use those arguments as follows:

```
<div>
  <form id="form1" action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post">
      <input type="number" name="op1"><br>
      <input type="number" name="op2"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="ok">
  </form>
```

Hope this helps,

Ismael Trascastro